# Apache - RequestHeader unset Authorization by source IP range?

Tags: apache, rest, security

Basically I have an app (JIRA) and I want to restrict Basic Auth against the API for external users. I originally tried this:

```
<Location "/rest/api/2/" >
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from all
     Allow from 10.
</Location>
```

And while that worked, it caused UI issues within the app itself when the app tried to call it's own API. Specifically I would get errors like this in Chrome:

```
Failed to load resource: rest/api/2/issue/picker?currentJQL=project+%3D+TER+AND+resolution+%3D+Unresolved+ORDER+BY+priority+DESC%2C+updated+DESC&currentIssueKey=TER-8&showSubTasks=true&showSubTaskParent=true&appId=&query=t&_=1524154354555 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

So now I am trying to use the

```
RequestHeader unset Authorization
```

Which also seems to work, but I need a way to not have that rule apply to internal (10.anything IP) users. Suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the source IP of the jira server in the 10. range?

Comment: Yes. And it occurs to me I could just have internal API users ping that directly, rather than the Proxy.